# 20.04: screen frozen, alt+ctrl+fn does not invoke tty

Tags: keyboard, crash, xserver

I had opened 6-7 application(the memory is 16GB) on ubuntu 20.04, just as I opened a new tab in firefox, the whole screen was stuck-up. The screen was still showing the GUI of firefox, but when I moved mouse or pushed keyboard, the screen did not change anything(and the keyboard would light up when I push a key, but the keyboard light is set to off in my seesion). I tried Alt+F2, Alt+Ctrl+F1-7 and Alt+Ctrl+Fn+F1-7, none of these brought any change to the screen.

I have also tried SysRq key, but I am not sure which key is SysRq on my machine(Dell vostro 7500).

Now I have powered off my machine and restarted it, but I do not want to do this every time when I encounter this problem(this problem has happened several times).

Comment: Just after less than one day, things happen again, but this time with only three applications opening.

Comment: What is your question? If you want to give SysRq a try, first find out which key it is and make sure it is totally activated.

Comment: @Quasímodo Any suggestion is ok, after all I do not have any idea how to deal with this. Can you give me a good tutorial on SysRq?

Comment: Please don't take this as an offense, but you should generally search things for yourself. There are many posts here at AskUbuntu and around the web that show how to enable SysRq.